# EF5 (Code First) Dynamic/Variable TypeName

Tags: ef-code-first, data-annotations

I have a class with a Data Annotation Properties with the TypeName Specified. Everything works exactly as it should. For Unit Testing purposes I want to use a SQL Compact database instead of a sql server database. However Sql Compact does not support the XML datatype. They recommend you use `ntext`. The catch is it doens't affect my entity at all as both xml and `ntext` map to type `System.String`. Creating the database on the fly though is a hassle. Basically I want the `TypeName="XML"` when connecting to SQL Server and `TypeName="ntext"` when connecting to SQL Compact.

```
public class TechnicalStructure
{
    [Column("StructureAttributes", TypeName = "xml")]
    public string StructureAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer. I removed the TypeName attribute-property from the affected class Property and overrode the OnModelCreate method in the DbContext class. In there I specified the datatype. Here is a code example:

```
if (IsInUnitTestMode)
{
modelBuilder.Entity<TechnicalStructure>()
.Property(x => x.StructureType)
.HasColumnType("nvarchar");

modelBuilder.Entity<TechnicalStructure>()
.Property(x => x.StructureAttributes)
.HasColumnType("ntext");
}
else
{
modelBuilder.Entity<TechnicalStructure>()
.Property(x => x.StructureType)
.HasColumnType("char");

modelBuilder.Entity<TechnicalStructure>()
.Property(x => x.StructureAttributes)
.HasColumnType("xml");
}
```